# How to transform case-sensitive script meant to list duplicate files to case-insensitive?

Tags: linux, unix, terminal

This script will list all the files with same filenames even when they are in different (sub)directories or have different file extensions (or no extension at all):

```
declare -A array=() dupes=()
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do 
    base=${file##*/} base=${base%.*}
    if [[ ${array[$base]} ]]; then 
        dupes[$base]+=" $file"
    else
        array[$base]=$file
    fi
done < <(find /the/dir -type f -print0)

for key in "${!dupes[@]}"; do 
    echo "$key: ${array[$key]}${dupes[$key]}"
done
```

([source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48524/search-for-duplicate-file-names-within-folder-hierarchy/48549#48549))

I want to do exactly the same but also list files with the same filenames in different case. That means where all these files would be listed as duplicates:

```
/the/dir/file.txt
/the/dir/folder1/File
/the/dir/folder2/filE.JPG
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this line in your shell script:

```
base=`echo $base | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
```

This will convert all your file names to lowercase.  Voila - case insensitive hash keys.

Comment: Sorry for the really stupid question but how exactly would that final script look like? Wherever I put that line the results either stay case-sensitive or it only lists files with the same file extension.

Comment: You may also need this?  `file=\`echo $file | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'\``

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works. Just in case I'm not annoying already, would you know of a way where the output would preserve the case, not everything converted to lowercase? Not really essential but it would make it easier to orient myself.

Comment: Just create before and after variables, e.g., `file_before_tr=$file` and `file_after_tr=\`echo $file | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'\``